# quadratic residues and prime divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that exist a many infinitely positive integers $n$  such that $n^2+1$ have a prime divisor greater than $2n + \sqrt{2n}$.

I was trying to solve but without interesting advances.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are 2 distinct questions, and you should post them separately.

Comment: This is IMO 2008 Shortlist N6 (and also Question 3 on Day 1 of the contest); see page 50 of http://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2008SL.pdf for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

We know that there are infinitely many numbers n  such that n^2+1 is prime. And it is easy to prove that 2n+(2n)^0.5 < n^2+1.

Comment: As far as I know, we _don't know_ if there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ prime, it is an open problem.

Comment: It's known as [Landau's fourth problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems)